# Bookman Leading

Tags: text, typesetting, formatting

I am designing the interior for a novel using Bookman Old Style size 11pt.

Right now, due to input from readers, I have set a leading of 13.5pt.

Is that too large? I do not want the text to look like an elementary reader, but I do want to privilege readability.

Will a leading of 13.5pt be okay, or should I tighten it up?

Here is a copy of a version with 14p grid layout[image]

Comment: The leading in that scan looks fine to me at 14pt, but 13.5pt may also be ok, you just got to decide that yourself. Squeezing from 14 to 13.5 will not make it a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

11/13pt sounds right and 11/13.5pt is not far from that, if your readers asked for this it must be helpful to them. So, without seeing the actual page layout, I would say you should be fine.

Comment: Hello, I just tried to send you visuals, but failed.  I am trying to choose between a grid layout of 3.75 and 14.  I do not know where they went.  Sorry.  I give up,